# append files to an archive without reading/rewriting the whole archive

Tags: java, archive, tar

I've got many files that I want to store in a single archive file. My first approach was to store the files in a gzipped tarball. The problem is, that I've to rewrite the whole archive if a single file is added.
I could get rid of the gzip compression, but adding a file would still be expensive.

What other archive format would you suggest that allows fast append operations?

Comment: Are you able to write a container yourself, or do you need a well known algorithm to enable other people/systems to handle the result file?

Comment: I try avoid writing my own container. One reason is that people should be able to open the file, yes. I would also suppose that writing my own container causes more work and is initially lot more buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ZIP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) was designed to allow appends without a total re-write and is ubiquitous, even on Unix.

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java is highly related. I'm not sure if there's any (Java) implementation that allows appends without total rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

ZIP and TAR fomats (and the old AR format) allow file append without a full rewrite. However:

- The Java archive classes DO NOT support this mode of operation.
- File append is likely to result in multiple copies of a file in the archive if you append an existing file.
- The ZIP and AR formats have a directory that needs to be rewritten following a file append operation.  The standard utilities take precautions when rewriting the directory, but it is possible in theory that you may end up with an archive with a missing or corrupted directory if the append fails.