# Java - How to move a file into a zip file?

Tags: java, file, zip, move, unzip

That's it. I have a text file, and I need to move it to a (existing) Zip File in a given directory.

```
    File file = new File("C:\\afolder\\test.txt");
    File dir = new File(directoryToGo+"existingzipfile.zip");
    boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(dir, file.getName()));
```

But it does not work. Is there a way to move a file into a existing Zip File?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048669/how-can-i-add-entries-to-an-existing-zip-file-in-java

Comment: It's not gonna be nearly that simple. Java provides classes for managing compressed archives in `java.util.zip`, specifically [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3048744/275567).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm you could use something like:

```
public static void addFilesToExistingZip(File zipFile, File[] files) throws IOException {
    // get a temp file
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(zipFile.getName(), null);
    // delete it, otherwise you cannot rename your existing zip to it.
    tempFile.delete();
    boolean renameOk = zipFile.renameTo(tempFile);
    if (!renameOk) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "could not rename the file " + zipFile.getAbsolutePath() + " to " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
    ZipEntry entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    while (entry != null) {
        String name = entry.getName();
        boolean notInFiles = true;
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.getName().equals(name)) {
                notInFiles = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (notInFiles) { // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name)); // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
            int len;
            while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
        entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    } // Close the streams
    zin.close(); // Compress the files
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]); // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName())); // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        } // Complete the entry
        out.closeEntry();
        in.close();
    } // Complete the ZIP file
    out.close();
    tempFile.delete();
}
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.dzone.com/snippets/adding-files-existing-jar-file

Comment: BTW I just learned the hard way that adding two identically named ZipEntry objects to a ZipOutputStream will throw an exception. So when adding files be careful about what files you already have.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to build a new zip file:

- Open the existing zip file for reading
- Open a new zip file for writing
- Copy all the entries from the old zip file to the new one, ignoring an entry corresponding to your extra file, if there is one
- Add your extra file
- Close both the input and the output files
- Delete the old zip file
- Rename the new zip file to the old one's name

Comment: Thank you.But what if the zip file is actually a jar?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, here `uploadPath+fileName` is filename with its path:

```
String FileName="Urzip file name. zip";

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(uploadPath+fileName);
ZipOutputStream zipFile = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

// Then, here I have list of pdf files in a LIST:

// continuation ...
for (int i = 0; i < filename.size(); i++) {
    String file = filename.get(i);
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(uploadPath+file);
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file);
    zipFile.putNextEntry(entry);
    int len;

    while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        zipFile.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    zipFile.closeEntry();
    input.close();
}

// Next, here "downFile" is the other file which you have to add in your existing zip:

// continuation ...
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(uploadPath+downFile);

ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(downFile);
zipFile.putNextEntry(e);
int len;
while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    zipFile.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
zipFile.closeEntry();
input.close();

zipFile.close();
```

Comment: please fix the problem with missing keys - like _y_ - on your keyboard ;-)

Comment: curious: why do you insist on interspersing not-code into the code sections? That makes it hard to use the snippets via c&p ...

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Java 7 you have a zip filesystem provider which allows you to write this code:

```
final Path src = Paths.get("c:\\afolder\\test.txt");
final String filename = src.getFileName().toString();

final Path zip = Paths.get(directoryToGo, "existingzipfile.zip");
final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zip.toUri());
final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.emptyMap();

try (
    final FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
) {
    Files.move(src, zipfs.getPath("/" + filename),
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the class to  move the file to inside jar/zip folder based on accepted answer.
The accepted answer didn't hold full executable code ,So i have added the class which helps to move/copy the file to jar/zip 
    package ZipReader;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipWrite {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        File file=new File("F:/MyProjects/New folder/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar");
        File filetoPush=new File("F:/MyProjects/New folder/BestResponseTimeBalanceStrategy.class");
        File[] files=new File[1];
        files[0]=filetoPush;
        addFilesToExistingZip(file,files);
    }

    public static void addFilesToExistingZip(File zipFile, File[] files)
            throws IOException {
        // get a temp file
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(zipFile.getName(), null);
        // delete it, otherwise you cannot rename your existing zip to it.
        tempFile.delete();
        boolean renameOk = zipFile.renameTo(tempFile);
        if (!renameOk) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not rename the file "
                    + zipFile.getAbsolutePath() + " to "
                    + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
        ZipEntry entry = zin.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            String name = entry.getName();

            boolean notInFiles = true;
            for (File f : files) {
                if (f.getName().equals(name)) {
                    System.out.println(name);
                    notInFiles = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (notInFiles) {
                System.out.println("adding");
                // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name)); // Transfer bytes from the
                                                        // ZIP file to the
                                                        // output file
                int len;
                while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
            }
            entry = zin.getNextEntry();
        } // Close the streams
        zin.close(); // Compress the files
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            System.out.println("files[i].getName()-->"+files[i].getName());
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("com/mysql/jdbc/util/"+files[i].getName()));
            // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            // Complete the entry
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }
        // Complete the ZIP file
        out.close();
        tempFile.delete();
    }

}
```