# How to zip only .txt files using java

Tags: java

```
package codes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Rough {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "C:\\Users\\s13w63\\Desktop\\Zip";    

File dir = new File(FOLDER_PATH);

    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
            if (fileName.endsWith(".txt")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    for (File f : files)
    {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\s13w63\\Desktop\\Source.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos=new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        ZipEntry ze=new ZipEntry(f.getCanonicalPath());
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        zos.close();
        System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
    }
}
}
```

I tried this code to ZIP the files, it was showing the file names but not zipping them. Should I have to add anything..and it was showing there is error in code continue to compile??

Help me to solve this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - How to move a file into a zip file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905982/java-how-to-move-a-file-into-a-zip-file)

Comment: You're calling `ZipEntry(name)`. This code creates an entry with particular name. It doesn't actually write anything to zip file. Check out linked question to learn how to write contents of zip file.

Comment: @defaultlocale the solution in the linked question is obsolete; since Java 7+ you have a zip `FileSystem` available

Comment: @fge solution is still usable, though. Also linked question is still open so you can post new answer there. I'll be happy to upvote.

Comment: @defaultlocale the problem in this question is different since here there are several files to move; and here again, there is a cleaner solution than using a `FilenameFilter`. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bharat,
Please paste the error message that you see

Also, I see few issues with your approach.
You might need to do the below things

- Take out the definition of FOS and ZOS from the for loop and move it above it...
- The code to add the file is missing...
- Move zos.close() after the for loop
- You could use the below code to add contents of the text file to the ZipOutputStream

```
/**
* Adds a file to the current zip output stream
* 
* @param file
*            the file to be added
* @param zos
*            the current zip output stream
*/

private static void addFileToZip(File file, ZipOutputStream zos) {
        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
                 zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
                 byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                 int read = 0;
```

```
         while ((read = bis.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
             zos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
         }
         zos.closeEntry();
     } catch (IOException e) {
             //Take appropriate action
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use java.nio.file; it has a very nice solution to your problem.

Illustration:

```
final Path zipPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\s13w63\\Desktop\\Source.zip");

final Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\s13w63\\Desktop\\Zip");
final DirectoryStream<Path> dirstream
    = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.txt");

final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipPath.toUri());
final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.emptyMap();

String filename;

try (
    final FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
) {
    for (final Path entry: dirstream) {
        filename = dir.relativize(entry).toString();
        Files.copy(entry, zipfs.getPath("/" + filename));
    }
}
```

Yes, that's right, you can open a zip file as a `FileSystem`; as such, every operation in `Files` can be used "on a zip"!

This is JSR 203 for you; you even have `FileSystem` implementations in memory, over FTP, Dropbox, and others.

---

Note about the necessity to have the file name as a `String`: it is because you cannot `.resolve()` a `Path` against another if the other `Path` is from a different provider; I have published a package which solves this particular problem (among others) and has a [`MorePaths.resolve()` method](http://fge.github.io/java7-fs-more/com/github/fge/filesystem/MorePaths.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path)) for such cases.