# How to update a .class file to Jar in Java code?

Tags: java, jar

I compiled a class file and want to inject it into an existed jar file.
I tried but "jar" command is not a good solution, anyone can help on this?

Comment: _"jar" command is not a good solution_ why ?

Comment: You tried "jar" and it didn't work ? Did you get error msg ? What exactly is the problem with "jar" ?

Comment: An alternative is to create a `patch.jar` which you place earlier in your class path.

Comment: Basically, adding a file to an existing Jar file is (essentially) the same as adding files to an existing zip file. Take a look here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048669/how-can-i-add-entries-to-an-existing-zip-file-in-java

Comment: @MadProgrammer , I'm trying you way. Thanks

Comment: @JigarJoshi, jar is a little bit environment dependent, code is more cross-platform

Comment: How jar is platform dependent ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi , jar.exe in Windows and jar in Linux

Answer (score 0):

so 
I think you can decompress the jar, and copy your class file in the directory you compressed.
and re compress these files into a new jar file.

Comment: I also thought of this solution, but compare to inject a file to a existed jar, this way is risky. (Consider Manifest file, too big jar file, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate it in a script `jar` is your best bet. It's installed with the JDK and gets the job done.

If it's a one time operation you might want to use e.g. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or another archiving software that can handle the [jar file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) (which is basically a ZIP).