# How to unzip .apk file programatically from mobile ? and how to insert a file into it?

Tags: java, android

I have a .apk file in assets folder.I want to  unzip that .apk file and  insert a file in it and generate a .apk from mobile. How can i achieve it? give any suggestions.

Comment: You cannot unzip a apk file. You have to decompile it if possible..

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? do you want to install a apk from assets folder?

Comment: @Oli: You can! unzip an apk file because the compress algorythm is zip based.

Comment: @Reporter Oh ok, thanks ;) - to get the assets db its usefull

Comment: @user2380107 can you give us some background informations?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048669/how-can-i-add-entries-to-an-existing-zip-file-in-java and the menthonied related links can help for your task.

Comment: @Hussain: I want to install that .apk from assets folder before that i want to insert a .sql file into it. (is this process is possible under mobile?)

Answer (score 2):

APK files are ZIP files, therefore the classes below [java.util.zip](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) should serve you well. Note that deleting a file from a ZIP file is not that simple - therefore it would be easier to have an APK file without the file to be modified and the file separately.
Adding the modified file to the APK is much simpler.

Furthermore you have to consider that a modified APK file can not be installed on Android as it's signature is invalid. Hence you have to re-sign.

<s>Unfortunately the tool for signing an JAR/APK file is only included in the Java SDK and it is a native program for x86 which can't be executed on Android/ARM.</s>

Edit 2023-06: Google provides the [apksig library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/apksig?repo=google) (pure Java) which can sign (or verify) an APK file. The only part that is left is the aligning before signing. There is the [zipalign-java](https://github.com/Iyxan23/zipalign-java) project which seem to be able to handle most alignment cases.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you may need to rename the extension to .zip. ZipFile will work, though.

Comment: No, The programs and your code don't care about extensions. Only on Windows if you double click the file the extension matters.

Comment: Ah, ok. I know code doesn't care, but I wasn't sure if any of the zip API threw something if the file wasn't a recognized extension (zip,tar,etc)

Comment: @Robert: So is it possible to create a modified .apk (which can be installable on mpbile) from mobile and store it in external sd_card?

Comment: @Robert: How to re-sign a modified .apk file?

Comment: You have to add the MD5 hash of each file in the APK file into the MANIFEST.MF and the sign the MANIFEST.MF with an self-signed certificate. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signature_File

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do this. First, you have to:

1. Change the file extension from .apk to .zip.
2. Unzip it and now it became a folder.
3. Change, delete what you want.
4. Zip the folder.
5. Change the extension to from .zip to .apk
6. Sign the APK using apksigner.
7. Install it.