# Write a file into Java archive (JAR)

Tags: java, file-io, jar

I would like to write a file into Java archive (JAR).
What do I need to modify in my code?

[image]

```
private void menu_savegame(ActionEvent e) {
    File config = new File("config");
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(config);
        fw.append(Integer.toString(level.current));
        fw.append("\n");
        if (win){
            fw.append(Integer.toString(ballCount));
        }
        else{
            fw.append(Integer.toString(G));
        }
        fw.append("\n");
        fw.append(Integer.toString(liveLeft));
        fw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I just would like this file to be written not to the folder, but *into* the Game.jar file - I have there all the game resources (images).

Comment: Does it work? If not, do you get an error? What is the expected result, what is the acutal result?

Comment: I would add `fw.close()`

Comment: It work. But I would like to have it file INTO archive!

Comment: If you want to create a file in a directory, use the proper `Path`.

Comment: I understand, but HOW i must catch it.
I read images from archive using this
Player.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("player.png");

Comment: He's talking about writing to the game's jar file.

Comment: Since Java 7 you can use a [Zip File System Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) to write to the JAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont forget that JAR is a typical ZIP file. In provided link you can see how it is performed.

[zip manipulation with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048669/how-can-i-add-entries-to-an-existing-zip-file-in-java)

eventually, use external libraries like JBoss ShrinkWrap.

[here's link to api](http://docs.jboss.org/shrinkwrap/)

good luck!