# Prevent the EAR maven plugin from expanding and rezipping subdeployments during packaging

Tags: java, maven, maven-ear-plugin

We have switched the way an old project was built from the Eclipse to Maven and now we are trying to improve the build time (in Eclipse it was <10sec and in Maven it is >1min).

I have noticed that the EAR plugin expands and then re-zipps the subdeployments (WAR and EJB jars):

```
[2016-06-07 11:35:52] [DEBUG] Resolving ear modules ...
[2016-06-07 11:35:52] [DEBUG] Resolving ear module[war:com.my-group:MyProj_web]
[2016-06-07 11:35:52] [INFO] Copying artifact [war:com.my-group:MyProj_web:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT] to [MyProj_web.war]
[2016-06-07 11:35:52] [DEBUG] Created a temporary work directory: /home/andrew/ELuna/myproj/project/MyProj_ear/target/temp/MyProj_web
[2016-06-07 11:35:52] [DEBUG] Expanding: /home/andrew/ELuna/myproj/project/MyProj_ear/target/MyProj_ear-default-name/MyProj_web.war into /home/andrew/ELuna/myproj/project/MyProj_ear/target/temp/MyProj_web
[2016-06-07 11:36:08] [DEBUG] expand complete
[2016-06-07 11:36:08] [DEBUG] Zipping module
[2016-06-07 11:36:13] [INFO] Building zip: /home/andrew/ELuna/myproj/project/MyProj_ear/target/MyProj_ear-default-name/MyProj_web.war
[2016-06-07 11:36:13] [DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/
[2016-06-07 11:36:13] [DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/jsp/
[2016-06-07 11:36:13] [DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/lib/
[2016-06-07 11:36:13] [DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/classes/
[2016-06-07 11:36:13] [DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/classes/com/
[2016-06-07 11:36:13] [DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/classes/com/my-group/
[2016-06-07 11:36:13] [DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/classes/com/my-group/lib/
...............................
```

The problem in this case is that the WAR project has a lot of small icons and it takes too much time by expanding/zipping.

**Question 1**: why does the EAR maven plugin does so? If it simply needs to add the MANIFEST.MF file to the WAR, why not simply add that entry [to the existing ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048669/how-can-i-add-entries-to-an-existing-zip-file-in-java) (the file format of WAR==JAR==ZIP)?
**Question 2**: are there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact cause of this behavior seems to be the [`<skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html) setting of the plugin. So the workaround is not to use it, in which case the build time will get a bit faster.