# Is there a quick way to delete a file from a Jar / war without having to extract the jar and recreate it?

Tags: java, linux, jar

So I need to remove a file from a jar / war file.
I was hoping there was something like "jar -d myjar.jar  file_I_donot_need.txt"

But right now the only way I can see of doing this from my Linux command line (without using WinRAR/Winzip or linux equivalent) is to

- Do "jar -xvf" and extract the
  complete Jar file
- Remove the file(s) I don't need
- Rejar the jar file using "jar -cvf"

Please tell me there is a shorter way?

Comment: Since a "jar" is just a zip file, I suspect you'll have better luck on http://superuser.com.

Comment: You can also try writing a shell script to wrap the whole process. Something like `./myscript.sh -d <list of files>`

Answer (score 260, accepted):

```
zip -d file.jar unwanted_file.txt
```

jar is just a zip file after all. Definitely much faster than uncompressing/recompressing.

Comment: I more often have p7zip installed instead of `zip` and in this case it's important to specify file format: `7z d -tzip file.jar dir/unwanted_file.txt`

Comment: @martona I am getting the following error: zip error: Zip file structure

Comment: @Goaler444 I had the same error, but using 7z as lapo suggested worked for me.

Comment: How to delete a file from a child jar or grand child jar?

Comment: If you want to delete a folder in the jar, make sure there is a trailing slash on the unwanted folder: `zip -d file.jar unwanted_folder/`

Comment: Using 7z as @lapo suggested getting this error 
System error:
E_NOTIMPL

Comment: One more point which cost me quite some time: you can't delete a non-empty folder. One must first delete all files/folders before deleting their parent.

Comment: works also for *.txt and recursive (so be careful)

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to delete file in order to unsign signed jar, you can probably just make the .RSA file zero-sized. This can be accomplished with just `jar u`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24678645/653539 . (Worked for me, though I admit it's hack.)

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can copy all the entries of a jar except the one you want to delete. i.e. you have to make a copy but don't need to create the individual files.

You can do this by

- creating a new jar.
- iterating though the Jar you have
- copy the entry from one jar to the other, skipping any files you want.
- close and replace the orginal jar if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this programatically, can use the Zip File System to treat zip/jar files as a file system. This will allow you to edit, delete, and add files to the jar file.

See [Appending files to a zip file with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer for me was in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520822/is-there-a-quick-way-to-delete-a-file-from-a-jar-war-without-having-to-extract#comment26262497_4520932) by [lapo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166524/lapo) on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520932/266531) on this post.

User [lapo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166524/lapo) [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520822/is-there-a-quick-way-to-delete-a-file-from-a-jar-war-without-having-to-extract#comment26262497_4520932):

> I more often have `p7zip` installed instead of zip and in this case it's important to specify file format: `7z d -tzip file.jar dir/unwanted_file.txt`

User lapo's comment is in response to an answer suggesting using `zip -d` directly since the .jar files are like .zip archives but not exactly the same format. Like others, I wasn't able to use `zip -d file.jar unwanted_file.txt`. That would lead to

> zip error: Zip file structure invalid

But, I was able to install `p7zip` via `brew install p7zip`, and then I was able to delete using `7z d -tzip file.jar unwanted_file.txt`.