# Not able to send email via Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, smtp

I am getting this error when trying to send emails via gmail smtp inside servlet
it works locally when tested but not inside google engine
i added the libs under web-inf/libs [activation.jar-smtp.jar- mailapi.jar - mail.jar]
any idea how i can fix it!!

Error:
`javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest` `error for javax/mail/Message.class at com.google.appengine.run`

Code Snapshot:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
 props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
 //props.put("mail.debug", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
 javax.mail.Session sess = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props);
 Transport transport = sess.getTransport(); 
 transport.connect();
 transport.send(message);
```

Comment: From the excpetion trace it looks like your code is deployed on appengine.
If i remember correctly app engine does not allow you to send email.
Please recheck the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot use](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#no_signed_jars) signed jar files on Google app engine.

As indicated on the web page, you should try to unsign it, specifically the `mail.jar` because the error is indicating `javax/mail/Message.class`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757083/how-do-i-unsign-a-jar) for an example