# ASP.NET: Insert data in a ZIP file without having to re-write the entire ZIP file?

Tags: asp.net, file, zip, compression

My question is a bit similar to this one but it is with ASP.NET and my requirements are slightly different: [Android append files to a zip file without having to re-write the entire zip file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739583/android-append-files-to-a-zip-file-without-having-to-re-write-the-entire-zip-fil)

I need to insert data to a zip-file downloaded by users (not much 1KB of data at most, this is data for [Adword off-line conversion](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031?hl=en) actually). The zip-file is downloaded through an ASP.NET website. Because the zip file is already large enough (10's of MB) to avoid overloading the server, I need to insert these data without re-compressing everything. I can think of two ways to do this.

- **Way A**: Find a zip-technology that lets embed a particular file in the ZIP file, this particular file being embedded uncompressed. Assuming there is no checksum, it'd be then easy to just override the bits of this un-compressed file with my specific data, in the zip file itself. If possible, this would have to be supported by all unzip tools (Windows integrated zip, winrar, 7zip...).
- **Way B**: Append an extra file to the original ZIP file without having to recompress it! This extra file would have to be stored in an embedded folder in the ZIP file.

I looked a bit at [SevenZipSharp](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) which has an enumeration `SevenZip.CompressionMode` with values `Create` and `Append` that leads me to think that **Way B** could be implemented. [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) seems also to work pretty well with Stream according to FAQ.

But if **Way A** could be possible I'd prefer it much since no extra zip library would be needed on the server side!

Comment: Why if you add a file (way A) you think it'll be recompressed? It won't. Each file zipped in a ZIP archive has its own dictionary (if file is appended or it'll overwrite existing...well it depends on library implementation and case by case). Anyway you have to use an external library (unless you want to manage by yourself zip file format issues).

Comment: Adriano, Way A is not about adding a file, but overriding the content of a file already embedded in the archive, without having to use a zip library for that.

Comment: You can override such file (as I said in comment) only if its size doesn't extend existing one AND to do that you have to handle ZIP file format stuff by yourself. A library will do it for you in the right way (also updating CRC).

Comment: This sounds interesting, you mean that the ZIP library will modify only bits in the ZIP file, relative to the file overridden, with the condition that the new overiden file content is smaller in size than the old one. Is there any documentation somewhere about this?

Comment: Library source code. It's really an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks so much Adriano, I've been able to achieve what I wanted thanks to your hint, see my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) I am able to do what I want in a very resource efficient way:

```
using System.IO;
using Ionic.Zip;

class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      byte[] buffer;
      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
         using (var zip = new ZipFile(@"C:\temp\MylargeZipFile.zip")) {

            // The file on which to override content in MylargeZipFile.zip
            // has the path  "Path\FileToUpdate.txt"
            zip.UpdateEntry(@"Path\FileToUpdate.txt", @"Hello My New Content");
            zip.Save(memoryStream);
         }
         buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
      }
      // Here the buffer will be sent to httpResponse
      // httpResponse.Clear();
      // httpResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MylargeZipFile.zip");
      // httpResponse.ContentType = "application/octe-t-stream";
      // httpResponse.BinaryWrite(buffer);
      // httpResponse.BufferOutput = true;

      // Just to check it worked!
      File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\Result.zip", buffer);
   }
}
```