# how to replace a jar in another jar file?

Tags: java, zip, inputstream, outputstream

I am trying to replace a modified property.jar in WAS.jar, what's the quickest way to do this? Replacing normal files back to a jar is very easily by using input/output stream. How can I do it with jar/ear types?

Please advise, thanks

Comment: What's the difference between the .jar file and any other file type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java) could help you?

Answer (score 0):

Three steps:

1. Unpack the JAR you want to change
2. Make your changes
3. Re-JAR it

I'm not saying that this is a good idea.  I don't see why you should have to do such a thing.  Don't consider supplying the steps as an endorsement.

Comment: re-jar is bad idea because you will need to use all classpath and manifest etc. again

Answer (score 0):

jar and ear files are zip-files.  What you need to do is equivalent to replacing an entry in a zip-file.

Comment: Just those you want to replace.