# Java.util.zip replace a single zip file

Tags: java, zipoutputstream

### Problem

I have an existing zipfile "main.zip". I want to replace a single file in it, "say main.zip/foo."

### I am aware of:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html

However, this does not do what I want, as it creates a new Zip file -- and thus I'd have to add in all the existing entries in main.zip also.

### Question:

Is there a way to "replace" a single file within a Zip archive in Java? (Without re-creating a new zip archive and copying over all the old data).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java appending files into a zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300115/java-appending-files-into-a-zip)

Comment: From one of those questions comes this most succinct summary: "Unfortunately, Java can't update Zip files... You will need to unpack it to a temp folder, add files there and pack it back again."

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: My question is a dup. I think we should close (but not delete) the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you are in luck.

Using the java 7 `java.nio.file.FileSystem` together with `Files.copy()` I managed to insert a textfile into a large zipfile in a split second.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Path myFilePath = Paths.get("c:/dump2/mytextfile.txt");

    Path zipFilePath = Paths.get("c:/dump2/myarchive.zip");
    try( FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath, null) ){
        Path fileInsideZipPath = fs.getPath("/mytextfile.txt");
        Files.copy(myFilePath, fileInsideZipPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It 'mounts' the zip using the ZipFileSystem Provider. Then you can just copy whatever you want into it. The changes seem to take place on `fs.close()`

[Read more @ oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html)

Comment: I like. (Learning about java.nio.file.FileSystem is especially cool). Thanks1

Comment: hey @AkselWillgert could you help me whit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647152/writing-modifying-or-adding-a-file-inside-a-zip#comment20464753_14647152)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the ZipFileSystem will run out of memory when trying to use Files.copy to add a large file in this manner.

Comment: Think I tried it for relatively large files, but might recall incorrectly. What sizes and computer system are you talking about here?

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. By using this method I can add the txt file to the main folder of zip but I can't go deeper. I want to add a txt file into a folder which is inside the zip file. When I change the code to Path fileInsideZipPath = fs.getPath("res/raw/mytextfile.txt");  I get java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: res/raw. Do you know a method to manage this?

Comment: does the folder exist otherwise you need to create it. I think the names inside the zip are case-sensitive also

Comment: Yes, the folder exists and all names are lower case.

Comment: Thank you very much, Aksel Willgert.

Comment: If the file already exists in the zip file, you will get a `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException`. In this case you have to add a `CopyOption` like this: `Files.copy(myFilePath, fileInsideZipPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`