# writing (modifying or adding) a file inside a zip

Tags: java, file, zip, nio, archive

I've followed the instructions in 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787318/java-util-zip-replace-a-single-zip-file), using the code in there I've been able to add a file to a zip file without uncompressing and recompresing it, but i have a problem, let me show you my code:

```
private void saveFileIntoProjectArchive(Path pathOfFile) {
    this.projectArchiveFile.setWritable(true, false);
    Path zipFilePath = Paths.get(this.projectArchiveFile.getAbsolutePath()),
            pathToSaveInsideZIP = null;
    FileSystem fs;
    try {
        fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath, null);
        pathToSaveInsideZIP = fs.getPath(pathOfFile.toString().substring((int) this.transactionalProjectFolder.getAbsolutePath().length()));
        System.out.println("Coping from:\n\t"+pathOfFile+"\nto\n\t"+pathToSaveInsideZIP);
        Files.copy(pathOfFile, pathToSaveInsideZIP, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        System.out.println("Done!!!");
        fs.close();
    } catch (java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    projectArchiveFile.setWritable(false, false);
}
```

what I'm trying to do is, i have many files for a same project, that project is an archive (ZIP, which in the code is referenced by a java.io.File called projectArchiveFile, an instance variable of my class) containing all of those files, when I want to work with certain file inside my archive, i uncompress only that file into a folder which has an structure identical to the one inside my archive (ZIP, projectArchiveFile), the reference to that folder is a java.io.File called transactionalProjectFolder, also an instance variable of my class. But is giving me this error:

coping from:
    C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Begin of Archive stucure\Another folder replica of the archive structure\An Excel File.xlsm
to
    \Begin of Archive stucure\Another folder replica of the archive structure\An Excel File.xlsm

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Begin of Archive stucure\Another folder replica of the archive structure\ at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.checkParents(ZipFileSystem.java:846)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newOutputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:515)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.newOutputStream(ZipPath.java:783)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:276)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:170)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2826)
at java.nio.file.CopyMoveHelper.copyToForeignTarget(CopyMoveHelper.java:126)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1222)
```

the rest of the stack trace are my classes.

I've been able to write in the root of the archive(zip), but whenever i try to write inside of a folder which is inside of the archive (zip) it fails, as you can notice in the stack trace, it says that `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Begin of Archive stucure\Another folder replica of the archive structure\` and it stops right before the name if the file which I'm trying to copy, I'M ENTIRELY SURE that the path inside the zip exist and it is appropriately spelled it just do not want to write (I've trying with Files.copy and Files.move) the file inside the archive, I've been stuck in this for a month, I don't know what else to do, any suggestion will be appreciated!!!

thanks in advance! :)...

Comment: Maybe Windows backslashes `\` should be replaced by standard slashes `/` too.

Comment: no, in deed I'm using `File.separator` for that work, so it can't be the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even tho you are sure the path exists, I would for troubleshooting add below row and see what directory structure it creates.

The error indicate the directories are missing inside the zip. Could be you are using some weird folder names not supported by zip etc..

```
System.out.println("Coping from:\n\t"+pathOfFile+"\nto\n\t"+pathToSaveInsideZIP);

Files.createDirectories(pathToSaveInsideZIP);  // add this row

Files.copy(pathOfFile, pathToSaveInsideZIP, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
System.out.println("Done!!!");
```

Comment: wow, it work but is doing something really strange, that i didn't think it was possible, by doing that i have two files in the same directory with the same name :S any idea why?

Comment: I tried to delete the file before the copy, but since this method is different to the File.delete method, which is boolean, this doesn't gives you any feedback to determine whether or not the file was deleted...

Comment: It has to do with upper/lower case in directory names. if you first copy it into Blah/myFile.txt and then blah/myFile.txt you will end up with two files with the same name in the same dir :) (atleast that is how it look on windows) If you unzip the archive you will be asked to overwrite a file. I guess (havnt tested) it will create both blah/ and Blah/ if you unzip on linux

Comment: yhep, that exactly what it does, it ask me if I want to overwrite the file when i decompress it, about the upper/lower cases no, I'm sure (by printing) that the two strings (paths) are the same...

Comment: could be different representation of spaces or some other character then. Im just guessing wildly :)

Comment: i think what needs to be done is that you simppify the path and filename. then step by step you introduce more and see where it breaks

Comment: I found that the method `Files.deleteIfExists` is returning true and the documentation for that method explicitly says : "true if the file was deleted by this method; false if the file could not be deleted because it did not exist" but when i check on the archive (by decompressing it) the file remains, do you think this could be a bug?

Comment: well, even when I haven't been able to resolve this yet, getting 2 strange behaviors (1: `FileAlreadyExistsException` even when the `REPLACE_EXISTING` option is set, 2: I cannot delete some files of the zip using neither of these two functions `Files.delete` and `Files.deleteIfExists` this is the most accurate answer...  thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to try out the [TrueZip](https://truezip.dev.java.net/) it's easy to use, it exposes any archive into a virtual file system, then you can append, delete or edit any file inside the archive easily.

Comment: it seams to be a good alternative, but the eclipse public licence does not allow me to use it because of my company :/ ...