# Java 7 zip file system provider doesn't seem to accept spaces in URI

Tags: java, java-7

I have been testing all possible variations and permutations, but I can't seem to construct a FileSystemProvider with the zip/jar scheme for a path (URI) that contains spaces. There is a very simplistic test case available at [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html). I took the liberty of modifying the example and just adding spaces to the URI, and it stops working. Snippet below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
        env.put("create", "true");
        URI uri = new URI("jar:file:/c:/dir%20with%20spaces/zipfstest.zip");
        Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\dir with spaces");
        if(Files.exists(dir) && Files.isDirectory(dir)) {
            try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {}
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code (Windows, JDK7u2, both x32 and x64), I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 12: file:/c:/dir with spaces/zipfstest.zip
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.uriToPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:87)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:107)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:322)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:272)
```

If I use + instead of %20 as the space escape character, a different exception is thrown:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\dir+with+spaces\zipfstest.zip
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:229)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:430)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:170)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.<init>(ZipFileSystem.java:116)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:117)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:322)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:272)
```

I might be missing something very obvious, but would this indicate a problem with the supplied ZIP/JAR file system provider?

EDIT:

Another use case based on a File object, as requested in coments:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {
            File zip = new File("C:\\dir with spaces\\file.zip");
            URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zip.toURI().toURL());
            Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
            env.put("create", "true");
            if(zip.getParentFile().exists() && zip.getParentFile().isDirectory()) {
                FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown again as:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 12: file:/C:/dir with spaces/file.zip
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.uriToPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:87)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:107)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:322)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:272)
```

Comment: Establish a file object, check it `exists()`, then call `File.toURI().toURL()`.  What output do you get?

Comment: Added another use case that shows the same issue reported when the URI is constructed from a file object. No need to check if the file exists, the property map create=true ensures it gets created if it doesn't exist

Comment: Do the same check with the directory then.

Comment: There, added directory existence checks, that's not why the code fails... Same exceptions are still thrown within the ZipFileSystemProvider.

Answer (score 6):

Actually further analysis does seem to indicate there is a problem with the ZipFileSystemProvider. The uriToPath(URI uri) method contained within the class executes the following snippet:

```
String spec = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();
int sep = spec.indexOf("!/");
if (sep != -1)
  spec = spec.substring(0, sep);
return Paths.get(new URI(spec)).toAbsolutePath();
```

From the JavaDocs of URI.getSchemeSpecificPart() we can see the following:

> The string returned by this method is equal to that returned by the
>   getRawSchemeSpecificPart method except that **all sequences of escaped
>   octets are decoded**.

This same string is then passed back as an argument into the new URI() constructor. Since any escaped octets are de-escaped by getSchemeSpecificPart(), if the original URI contained any escape characters, they will not be propagated to the new URI - hence the exception.

A potential workaround - loop through all the available filesystem providers and get the reference to the one who's spec equals "jar". Then use that to create a new filesystem based on path only.

Comment: The workaround for this bug is to double-escape the spaces - i.e. %20 -> %2520 and then the file with space characters works. Completely nonsensical, but it seems to work

Comment: You are right Pete, with doubly encoded octets, uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() will decode them to the "correct" representation (%20), and then that string will get passed to the new URI() constructor which will happily accept it :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in Java 7 and it has been marked as fixed in Java 8 (see [Bug ID 7156873](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7156873)). The fix should also be backported to Java 7, but at the moment it's not determined that which update will have it (see [Bug ID 8001178](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8001178)).

Comment: Looking at the submit date of that bug, I'm guessing that you submitted it. ;) Anyways, I posted this answer here to tell others that when it will be fixed.

Comment: I think the fix is broken in Java 8 - but I'll need to check again in the build that comes out in a week.

See https://gist.github.com/stain/5591903 - I am unable to open again the ZIP given its own URI, and also this breaks regression with Java 7.

Answer (score 5):

The jar: URIs should have the escaped zip-URI in its scheme-specific part, so your jar: URI is simply wrong - it should rightly be double-escaped, as the jar: scheme is composed of the host URI, !/ and the local path.

However, this escaping is only implied and not expressed by the minimal URL "specification" in [JarURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html). I agree however with the raised bug in JRE that it should still accept single-escaped, although that could lead to some strange edge-cases not being supported.

As [pointed out by tornike and evermean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233431/412540) in another answer, the easiest is to do FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, null) - but this does not work when you want to pass and env with say "create"=true.

Instead, create the jar: URI using the component-based constructor:

```
URI jar = new URI("jar", path.toUri().toString(), null);
```

This would properly encode the scheme-specific part.

As a JUnit test, which also confirms that this is the escaping used when opening from a Path:

```
@Test
public void jarWithSpaces() throws Exception {
    Path path = Files.createTempFile("with several spaces", ".zip");
    Files.delete(path);

    // Will fail with FileSystemNotFoundException without env:
    //FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, null);

    // Neither does this work, as it does not double-escape:
    // URI jar = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri().toASCIIString());                

    URI jar = new URI("jar", path.toUri().toString(), null);
    assertTrue(jar.toASCIIString().contains("with%2520several%2520spaces"));

    Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("create", "true");

    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jar, env)) {
        URI root = fs.getPath("/").toUri();    
        assertTrue(root.toString().contains("with%2520several%2520spaces"));
    } 
    // Reopen from now-existing Path to check that the URI is
    // escaped in the same way
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, null)) {
        URI root = fs.getPath("/").toUri();
        //System.out.println(root.toASCIIString());
        assertTrue(root.toString().contains("with%2520several%2520spaces"));
    }
}
```

(I did a similar test with "with\u2301unicode\u263bhere" to check that I did not need to use .toASCIIString())

Comment: Note that this does not work in the latest build of JDK8 (8 Build b89):
it triple escapes with "with%252520several%252520spaces" and fails to open the zip file with "FileSystems.newFileSystem(path) afterwards, as it instead created with%20several%20spaces5741225552244499206.zip.

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods to create a filesystem:

`FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);`

`FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipfile, null);`

When there is a space in a filename together with the above solution for creating a uri. It also works if you use a different method that doesn't take a uri as argument.