# How can you create a new zip file in Java and add a large directory of files to it?

Tags: java, filesystems, zip

I'm trying to add a directory of files to a zip.  The directory is around 150 files large.  A few, 5-75 files in, I keep getting a crash with the error message `"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."`

I tried a delay which may be helping but is certainly not solving the bug.

Using code from:
[Is it possible to create a NEW zip file using the java FileSystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733496/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-zip-file-using-the-java-filesystem)

```
final File folder = new File("C:/myDir/img");
for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        String filename = fileEntry.getName();
        String toBeAddedName = "C:/myDir/img/" + filename;
        Path toBeAdded = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(toBeAddedName).toAbsolutePath();
        createZip(zipLocation, toBeAdded, "./" + filename);
        System.out.println("Added file " + ++count);
        //Delay because 'file in use' bug
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } //1secs
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public static void createZip(Path zipLocation, Path toBeAdded, String internalPath) throws Throwable {
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //Check if file exists.
    env.put("create", String.valueOf(Files.notExists(zipLocation)));
    //Use a zip filesystem URI
    URI fileUri = zipLocation.toUri();  //Here
    URI zipUri = new URI("jar:" + fileUri.getScheme(), fileUri.getPath(), null);
    System.out.println(zipUri);
    //URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:"+zipLocation);    //Here creates the zip
    //Try with resource
    try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipUri, env)) {
        //Create internal path in the zipfs
        Path internalTargetPath = zipfs.getPath(internalPath);
        //Create parent dir
        Files.createDirectories(internalTargetPath.getParent());
        //Copy a file into the zip file
        Files.copy(toBeAdded, internalTargetPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the file is locked because it's in use, I don't see what else you can do other than perhaps display a message to the user and ask them to correct it.

Comment: @markspace it's the app itself which is locking the files.  That's why I tried adding a delay.

Comment: I'm now using a two second delay between files which IMHO is huge yet it is working.

Comment: I'd find it strange if a process could be prevented from deleting a file it _itself_ has locked (but I could be wrong). Are you sure no other process is locking the file? The error message would indicate that's the case. You can check this; see, for instance, [this question (windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/643312) or [this question (linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/97844/how-can-i-determine-what-process-has-a-file-open-in-linux).

Comment: Is it possible that you're adding the zip to itself?

Comment: @JBanana Nope.  Like I said the 2-secs delay solves the bug.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the links but I've now solved the bug by adding a huge delay between files.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that adding a delay is not a "proper" fix and is likely very fragile. If you got it to work and you're happy with it then I suppose you can leave it at that, but it might be good to investigate the fundamental issue and see if you can implement a more appropriate fix.

Comment: @Slaw You're right.  The delay isn't even helping much.  It does need recoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't promise this is the cause of your problem, but your code compresses files into a ZIP file in a strange, or at least inefficient, manner. Specifically, you're opening up a new `FileSystem` for each individual file you want to compress. I'm assuming you're doing it this way because that's what the Q&A you linked to does. However, [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733863/6395627) is only compressing *one* file whereas you want to compress *multiple* files at the same time. You should keep the `FileSystem` open for the entire duration of compressing your directory.

```
public static void compress(Path directory, int depth, Path zipArchiveFile) throws IOException {
    var uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipArchiveFile.toUri());
    var env = Map.of("create", Boolean.toString(Files.notExists(zipArchiveFile, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)));

    try (var fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
        Files.walkFileTree(directory, Set.of(), depth, new SimpleFileVisitor<>() {

            private final Path archiveRoot = fs.getRootDirectories().iterator().next();

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                // Don't include the directory itself
                if (!directory.equals(dir)) {
                    Files.createDirectory(resolveDestination(dir));
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                Files.copy(file, resolveDestination(file), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            private Path resolveDestination(Path path) {
                /*
                 * Use Path#resolve(String) instead of Path#resolve(Path). I couldn't find where the
                 * documentation mentions this, but at least three implementations will throw a 
                 * ProviderMismatchException if #resolve(Path) is invoked with a Path argument that 
                 * belongs to a different provider (i.e. if the implementation types don't match).
                 *
                 * Note: Those three implementations, at least in OpenJDK 12.0.1, are the JRT, ZIP/JAR,
                 * and Windows file system providers (I don't have access to Linux's or Mac's provider
                 * source currently).
                 */
                return archiveRoot.resolve(directory.relativize(path).toString());
            }

        });
    }
}
```

***Note:** The `depth` parameter is used in exactly the same way as `maxDepth` is in [`Files#walkFileTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,java.util.Set,int,java.nio.file.FileVisitor)).*

***Note:** If you only ever care about the files in the directory itself (i.e. don't want to recursively traverse the file tree), then you can use [`Files#list(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path)). Don't forget to close the `Stream` when finished with it.*

It's possible that you opening and closing the `FileSystem` over and over is causing your problems, in which case the above should solve the issue.