# Saving JPEG images as a Video in Android

Tags: android

Supposedly, using my application I take a few images which will be saved at a particular directory and saved as JPEGs.

IS it possible to pack these images together? Like into a video or tar or zip? So that I can send send these images to a backend (E.g. web server).

Is this possible? Or I could only send them 1 by 1?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java/2251676#2251676

Comment: Please change the title of your question it cause be misunderstood by other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making video files from images you have to use any video codec library like **FFMPEG** or anything else..

But for creating **.zip archive**..

Android has a in-built class [`ZipOutputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) support of **java.util.zip** package.

This class provides an implementation of `FilterOutputStream` that compresses data entries into a ZIP-archive output stream.

`ZipOutputStream` is used to write `ZipEntries` to the underlying stream. Output from `ZipOutputStream` conforms to the `ZipFile` file format.

Also look at this article this may be help you..

[Zipping Files with Android (Programmatically)](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)