# i want to overwrite the existing zipfile

Tags: java, zip

i want to overwrite the existing zip file(which mean i add new file in existing zip file) but here show this error (java.util.zip.ZipError: zip END header not found)

```
private void updateZip(String fileName, String scenarioDirectory){
        System.out.println("File Name : " +fileName);
        System.out.println("Scenario Directory : " +scenarioDirectory);
       String scenarioName ="12345";
       Path myFilePath = Paths.get(fileName);
       Path zipFilePath = Paths.get(scenarioDirectory);
       FileSystem fs;
   try {
       fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath,null);
       Path fileInsideZipPath = fs.getPath(scenarioName);
       Files.copy(myFilePath, fileInsideZipPath);
       fs.close();

   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Files.copy(myFilePath, fileInsideZipPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)`?

Comment: i tried above code only

Comment: @Aru i want to add new .txt file in existing zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

if your file exist then delete it ant after save the new.

Or Added a file directly in the zip code since this example  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17500924/4017037