# Is there a possible way to copy a file to a jar file?

Tags: java, file, jar, directory, copy

I would like to ask a question if there is **a way to copy a file(i.e. an image) to a .jar file**, because i want to deploy a program and i created folders along with the source codes(they are in the same location as the source codes) and the folders are inside the jar file (i used **Netbeans** to create the jar file)..... Now what i want is i would like to copy files choosen by a **JFileChooser** to the folders inside the jar file????
Any idea is heartily accepted..!!! Thanks in advance????

P.S.:
I already tried searching the net for answers but all they know is how to **copy the file inside the jar file to another directory**......

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you want to add the file images/image1.gif to the JAR file.

```
jar uf <fileName>.jar images/image1.gif
```

To change the directory use -c

```
jar uf <fileName>.jar -C
```

in this command

jar uf jar-file input-file(s)

In this command:

```
The u option indicates that you want to update an existing JAR file.
The f option indicates that the JAR file to update is specified on the command line.
jar-file is the existing JAR file that's to be updated.
input-file(s) is a space-delimited list of one or more files that you want to add to the Jar file.
```

[Related Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

A JAR file is a ZIP compressed file.

See this S.O. answer for a solutiion to add files to an exisiting ZIP archive: [Appending files to a zip file with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java)