# Tibco Zipping file

Tags: tibco

I have got a scenario in which I have got two files in a folder.One is .jpg format and other is .xmp format.I have to zip this folder.That means the final zip folder will contain both of these files.Is there is any way to zip them together in bw,without using java function.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java code activity you won't have to add any libraries as the java natively can manipulate the Zip archives .. check this [Appending files to a zip file with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java)

You can invoke it as a system command like `gzip mm/*`  in the External command activity

specify the script as the command to run in the External Command activity. The script runs the desired command and returns the process ID of the process it started. The return code of the script is stored in the return Code item of the External Command activity's output.

I hope this could help!