# Unable to use Zip File System (Java 7) in android-studio (5.0 Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been trying to replace a file in zip without extracting the zip. I tried using the most efficient answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504151/3397618

I'll paste the code below for reference however.

```
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
env.put("create", "true");
Path path = Paths.get("test.zip");
URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());
try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env))
{
    Path nf = fs.getPath("new.txt");
    try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(nf, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {
        writer.write("hello");
    }
}
```

Android Studio throws an error saying:
error: cannot find symbol variable Paths,
error: cannot find symbol method toUri(),
error: cannot find symbol class FileSystem,
error: cannot find symbol variable FileSystems.

Is it that android doesn't support Java 7 entirely?? Or do I need to do something to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has its own implementations of the Java library classes, and it doesn't have full support for everything that's in Oracle's libraries. The `java.nio.file.Path` class isn't in Android's implementation.

You can see documentation on what's available in Android's `nio` package at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html