# Does Android provide a Zip File System Provider to use with java.nio.file?

Tags: java, android, zip, nio

I am trying to use Java NIO's Zip File System on Android (API Level 30). I basically tried to implement the example found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).

The result is a `java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "jar" not found`.

I know that it's possible that Android just does not offer this file system provider. [Six years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339538/unable-to-use-zip-file-system-java-7-in-android-studio-5-0-lollipop) someone tried the same and failed because `java.nio.file.Path` was not a part of Android's implementation (which it now is!).

But since I did not find a definite answer during my research I still wonder whether I did something wrong. I tried comparing [the Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/package-summary) but did not find anything suspicious which is missing on Android.

Is it possible to use Java NIO's Zip File System on Android? Or do we have keep using the old school way?

Comment: I have exact the same problem. It looks like Google engineers are too lazy to port Oracle code.