# How to append a text file to existing zip file in java?

Tags: java, azure

How do I insert a text file into an existing zip file where I have a stream of both the files.

Sample code is below:

I am using `IOutils.copy(in, out)`, but it is replacing the content. I need to insert the file and keep the existing content.

```
public URI createACopyOfFile(String requestId) throws Exception {
    BlobOutputStream blobOutputStream = null;
    BlobInputStream blobInputStream = null;
    try {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.print("Start createACopyOfFile ->" + startTime);
        long endTime = 0;
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.getContainerReference("tme-container");
        container.createIfNotExists();
        String blobName = "dummy.zip";
        CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(requestId + "/dummy_copy.zip");
        targetBlob.startCopyFromBlob(sourceBlob);

        blobOutputStream = targetBlob.openOutputStream();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(requestId + "/" + "activation.txt");
        blob.uploadText("Hello world");

        blobInputStream = blob.openInputStream();

        IOUtils.copy(blobInputStream, blobOutputStream);

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.print("End createACopyOfFile -> " + endTime);
        System.out.println("Total time taken for createACopyOfFile - > " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000);
        return targetBlob.getUri();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (blobInputStream != null)
                blobInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (blobOutputStream != null)
                blobOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific. Is this a Java-specific issue? Or is there something related to Azure (and if yes to Azure, how so? The question is unclear).

Comment: yes , it is related to java only but file are stored on azure platform.

I am using blob storage for storing a large file and on runtime i have to insert a file into a large file which is there on azure.

Comment: Sample code i have attached . Please check

Comment: when i did IOUtils.copy(blobInputStream, blobOutputStream); all the content on inputstream is copied and replacing the existing content

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell you that there is no ways to do it by azure SDK. When you add file to the zip file, the file will 
reorganize its content and generate a new zip file.
There is one method that you can download the .zip file and append file in local by JAVA. After then, you can upload your file to azure storage again. But your file is a big file, so it's not a feasible method.

The references:
[Appending files to a zip file with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java?rq=1)

Hope it helps. Any concerns, please feel free to let me know.