# Adding to an existing zip file in scala

Tags: scala, hdfs, zip

I have a zip file in hdfs and i need to add a file to the zip and save in the same HDFS location. Any examples would be appreciated.

I have the following code.

```
  val filePattern =  s"${hdfsFolderPath}/${filePath}.txt"
  val zipFilePath = hdfsWrapper.getFileNameFromPattern(s"${targetFilePath}/*.zip")

  if (hdfsWrapper.filter(filePattern).size() > 0)
    {
      Try
      {
        val zipEntry = new ZipEntry(filePattern)
         val zos: ZipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFilePath))
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry)            
        zos.closeEntry()
        zos.close()
      }
    }
```

Would like to know if above code is right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your code would result in the zip file being replaced with a new one containing just the new file. See [Appending files to a zip file with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java) for an example of adding a file to a zip archive.

I'm not extremely familiar with HDFS, but I suspect that you can't write to that directly either, you probably have to create the new zip file and then replace it in HDFS