Why is my created zip file (using ZipOutputStream) invalid?
I've been trying to retrieve all the files in the current directory, create a zip file, and place all the files into that zip file. Currently, I'm able to retrieve all the files, but I'm not sure they're being properly added to the zip file, as I am unable to extract it; the specific error I'm getting when extracting is 'The Compressed (zipped) Folder '...' is invalid'.
Shown below is my current code. Just to illustrate what I'm trying to do, I first call my getPath method, which is simply to retrieve the path of the current directory. I then call createZipFile to create the compressed file, and from there, I create an array of Files from the current directory. Finally, I iterate over this array, calling zipFile on each File. I use try-with-resources for each stream in that method. It's worth noting that originally, the created zip file was not invalid, though it would only consist of the final file in the array. I added 'true' to the FileOutputStream (for appending), which led me to my current issue.
public static Path currentDirectory; // directory to zip
    public static File[] files; // files in current folder
    public static File newZip; // the created zip file

    // will retrieve all files in currentDirectory, and zip them
    public static void findFiles() {
        getPath();
        createZipFile();
        File thisFolder = new File(String.valueOf(currentDirectory)); // current folder
        files = thisFolder.listFiles(); // all files in current folder

        for (File f : files) {
            zipFile(f.getName());
        }
    }

    public static Boolean createZipFile() {
        newZip = new File("test.zip");

        try {
            if (!newZip.exists()) {
                if (newZip.createNewFile()) {
                    System.out.println("Zip file created!");
                    return true;
                }
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void zipFile(String fileName) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newZip, true)) {
            File inputFile = new File(fileName);
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
                try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
                    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    System.out.println("Zipping file "+fileName+"!");
    
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("ZOS Error: "+e.getMessage());
                }   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("FIS Error: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FOS Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // sets currentDirectory, i.e. folder to zip
    public static void getPath() {
        Path currentPath = Paths.get("");
        String pathString = String.valueOf(currentPath.toAbsolutePath());
        currentDirectory = Paths.get(pathString);
    }

I tried instead using getBytes on the fileName itself in zipFile. I thought this would more appropriately write the provided bytes to the file. However, I received the invalid zip file message again, and the program took significantly longer to execute.
I also looked for solutions online, and I saw that a common solution was to make sure the streams were closed. However, since I'm using try-with-resources, I'm fairly certain that doesn't apply for me.

I suspect that its the way you approach zipping your file. A quick check online shows that when writing multiple entries to a zip file, you should open the ZOS once, iterate through the files, writing each as a ZipEntry. then close your ZOS once you are done with everything. not open it and closing it per file as you do. I m guessing there is some metadata or symbols used to delimit the file, and processing it the way you do makes your zip file invalid

Do it like this: 1) Open FileOutputStream fos 2) Open ZipOutputStream zos 3) iterate over all files: File f: files 3) Create ZipEntry: final ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(f.getName()) 4) add to zos: zos.putNextEntry(ze); 5) copy all bytes (like you do) 6) repeat steps 3+4+5 for all remaining files 7) close all streams, done.

If you want to append to an existing ZIP file, look at the answers to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434

@pebbleunit Thanks, I tried opening it once and iterating through each File within (opening a FIS as well), and it's working.

@JayC667 Thanks a lot; followed a similar process, and it's working now.

Problem hides in this line new FileOutputStream(newZip, true).
You can't append one zip to another and treat it as one big zip.
You need to create ZipOutputStream and add all your files to it.
